# how to calculate pandas DataFrame with several outcome?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have Pandas Dataframe:

```
index                         value_col   1       2      3      4      5      6      7 
2022-01-31 23:53:00-08:00    9.407500000  False  False   True  False  True   True  False 
2022-01-31 22:53:00-08:00   13.635000000   True  False  False  False  True  False   True 
2022-01-31 21:53:00-08:00   15.880000000   True  False  False  False  True  False   True 
2022-01-31 20:53:00-08:00   22.335000000   True  False  False  False  True  False   True 
2022-01-31 19:53:00-08:00   27.767500000   True  False  False  False  True  False   True
```

I need to calculate `Average "value_col"` based on column  `"2" and "5"` so final result should look like this:

```
             "2"                                     "5"                                    
"if True(2): sum(value_col)/count"   "if True(5): sum(value_col)/count"
```

I did make research on internet, but I have found many Sum examples but they are all not working as I need.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: 2 columns as I should in the middle.

Comment: if you want columns, how does `sum(value_col)` work?

Comment: it should be just summary of all values with True in that column.

Comment: Try: `df.loc[df['2'], 'value_col'].mean()` and `df.loc[df['5'], 'value_col'].mean()`

Comment: the result is 28.767 but it should be way higher. There is 740 rows with values between 10-20  and maybe half of them is True

Comment: Isn't actually too high? If values are between 10-20, the average should be between 10-20, no?

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should look:

```
df.loc[df['2'], 'value_col'].mean()
```

I test it and its working fine. Thanx to Enke!